# Get attribute of a different class in a form when clicking a button

Tags: jquery

When I click on the Delete Button, how can I get the value of art-no in jquery?

```
<form id="artForm" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="sequence" value="27" art-no="27">
<input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" id="submitbutton">
</form>
```

In using jQuery like this:

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
alert (".sequence").attr("art-no");
return false;
});
```

This should actually have worked, but I keep getting .sequence in the alert box. Is it because it's hidden?

Comment: Thanks to all of you for pointing that I missed the class="sequence". I added a class and it works fine now.

Comment: Norman, if you found your answer below please accept it, so future visitors can also learn the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, this is working solution:

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
    alert ($("[name='sequence']").attr("art-no"));
    return false;
});
```

And I have some advices;

- That hidden field has no class name, so you can't use `.sequence` for selector, you have to use `[name='sequence']` or you can give it `sequence` class and use it `.sequence`
- Instead of making up your own properties you can use `data` properties and [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/), use it like `data-art-no="27"` and access it like `.data('art-no')`
- Last, use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) insted of `return false`.

Here is your revised code:

```
$(".delete").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert ($("[name='sequence']").data("art-no"));
});
```

Comment: I agree that using `data-` attributes is better, but note that `.data('art-no')` will attempt type conversion whereas `.attr('data-art-no')` will return the original string value.

Comment: Thank You. I added the class="sequence" and it works great now.

Answer (score 3):

Add `class="sequence"` in your input which now has just a name and then replace

```
alert (".sequence").attr("art-no");
```

with

```
alert ($(".sequence").attr("art-no"));
```

or better

```
alert ($(this).prev(".sequence").attr("art-no"));
```

in order to be sure you have the correct element if you use the `sequence` class more than once (which is usually the reason to use a class and not an id).

If you don't want to add a class or an id, the selector will be `input[name=sequence]` :

```
alert ($("input[name=sequence]").attr("art-no"));
```

Comment: Thank You. I added the class="sequence" and it works great now.